# Как из трех Bitmap сделать один? [Android]

Tags: android, java, bitmap

Есть три картинки в памяти устройтсва в формате .png. Необходимо из них сделать одну, то есть взять от каждой по 33% ширины и объеденить в одну.

Прорыл все что мог, но ничего толком не нашел.

Нашел вот что, но не могу приспособить к себе!

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap c, Bitmap s) {
    Bitmap cs = null;

    int width, height = 0;

    if(c.getWidth() > s.getWidth()) { 
      width = c.getWidth() + s.getWidth(; 
      height = c.getHeight()); 
    } else { 
      width = s.getWidth() + s.getWidth(); 
      height = c.getHeight(); 
    }

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(c, 0f, 0f, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(s, c.getWidth(), 0f, null); 
    //notice that drawing in the canvas will automagically draw to the bitmap
    //as well
    return cs; 
  }
```

Помогите кто может.

Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ну так вызовите метод combineImages 2 раза:

```
Bitmap ab = combineImages(a, b);
Bitmap abc = combineImages(ab, c);
```